# Free memory after use [nodejs]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was running a test to check query times on mongodb if a document has a lot of data. The code used is:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email       : String,
    password    : String,
    dob         : Date,
    phone       : String,
    misc1       : Array,
    misc2       : Array,
    misc3       : Array,
    misc5       : Array,
    misc6       : Array,
    misc7       : Array,
    misc8       : Array,
    misc9       : Array,
    misc10      : Array,
    misc11      : Array,
    misc12      : Array,
    misc13      : Array,
    misc14      : Array,
    misc15      : Array
});

var Test = mongoose.model('Test', testSchema);

var email = 'someone';
var password = 'very safe password';
var dob = new Date();
var phone = 'this is not a phone number';
var dummyObject = {
    title: 'title',
    story: 'story',
    createdOn: new Date(),
    modifiedOn: new Date(),
    author: 'somebody'
};

var dummyArray = [];

console.log('start creating dummy arrays');

for(var i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
    dummyArray.push(dummyObject)
}

console.log('dummy arrays created');

var test = new Test({
    email       : email,
    password    : password,
    dob         : dob,
    phone       : phone,
    misc1       : dummyArray,
    misc2       : dummyArray,
    misc3       : dummyArray,
    misc5       : dummyArray,
    misc6       : dummyArray,
    misc7       : dummyArray,
    misc8       : dummyArray,
    misc9       : dummyArray,
    misc10      : dummyArray,
    misc11      : dummyArray,
    misc12      : dummyArray,
    misc13      : dummyArray,
    misc14      : dummyArray
});


module.exports = function () {
    for(var j = 0; j < 200; j++) {
        console.log(j);
        (function (j) {
            test.save(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(j + 'th record saved')
                }
            })
        })(j)
    }
};
```

But when I run this function two things happen which I don't understand:

1. The memory used by the node process: 2.83GB, it isn't getting freed.
2. Only 199 records get saved, 1 - 199 records get saved, there was no log for 0th record.

If tested with small values of `j` <= 50, you will notice that the `"0th record saved"` log does get printed. Even so, the RAM consumed doesn't get freed.

---

Hardware Overview:

- Model Name:  Mac mini
- Model Identifier:    Macmini7,1
- Processor Name:  Intel Core i5
- Processor Speed: 2.6 GHz
- Number of Processors:    1
- Total Number of Cores:   2
- L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
- L3 Cache:    3 MB
- Memory:  8 GB

I am using the activity monitor to check the amount of ram consumed by my node process.

---

## Update 1:

for `j = 50`, the memory (1.22GB) does get free (90MB) in >2 minutes.

---

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I free RAM once a process is complete?

Comment: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2874

Comment: Once a process has _exited_, any memory it used will revert back to the OS. The OS will determine what to do with it (unused memory is wasted memory, so usually, an excess of free memory will be used for I/O buffers).